Why for a one-parameter subgroup $\phi$ of $G$ there is a vector field $X$ such that $\frac{d\phi^{\mu} (t)}{dt}=X^{\mu}(\phi (t))$?
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to G$ a one-parameter subgroup of $G$; i.e., $\phi (t)\phi (s)=\phi (t+s)$. Given a one-parameter $\phi$, why there is a vector field $X$ such that $\frac{d\phi^{\mu}(t)}{dt}=X^{\mu}(\phi (t))$?
